# Kernel in categorical sense

Tags: category-theory

The question that i have is to understand better this concept. This notion of kernel is really general, and i want to know the real difference to the algebric kernel, for exemple, in categories like Grp and Ring, all morphisms have kernels in the categorical sense?

Comment: kernels are best understood in the context of abelian groups. Other than that, I don't quite understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Don't you mean abelian *categories* ?

Comment: @Pece oh my :) yes! thank you! Abelian categories!!!

Comment: Have you read this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(category_theory)

Comment: It is an easy exercise to check that the various definitions at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel#as_a_pullback agree with the usual notion of kernel in Set, Grp, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The notion of kernel is defined in a *category with zero object*(you can find more different definitions at [nlab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel)).

**Definition 1.(zero object)** Let $A$ be a category, $0\in A$ be its object. The object $0$ is called *the zero object of $A$* iff $0$ is both an initial object and a terminal object of $A$. In this case $A$ is called *a category with zero object*. If zero object exists, then it is unique up to isomorphism. For any two objects $a,b\in A$ we can define *the zero morphism* $0_{a,b}\colon a\to b$, which is a unique morphism from $a$ to $b$, that factors through $0$.

**Definition 2.(equalizer)** Let $A$ be a category, $a,b\in A$ be its objects, $f,g\colon a\to b$ be its arrows. Let $c\in A$ be an object of $A$ and $h\colon c\to a$ be an arrow. Then the pair $(c,h)$ is called *the equalizer of the pair* $(f,g)$(denoted by $Eq(f,g)$) iff the following two properties hold:

1). $f\circ h=g\circ h$;

2).for any object $d\in A$ and for any arrow $k\colon d\to a$, such that $f\circ k=g\circ k$, there exists a unique $x\colon d\to c$, such that $h\circ x=k$.

**Definition 3.(kernel)** Let $A$ be a category with zero object $0$, and let $f\colon a\to b$ be its arrow. The kernel of $f$(denoted by $Ker(f)$), if it exists, is the equalizer of the pair $(f,0_{a,b})$. So we have a formula:
$$
Ker(f)=Eq(f,0_{a,b}).
$$

The advantage of such categorical definition is that in this definition kernel is a limit(because equalizer is a limit(it is a limit of a diagram $\downarrow\downarrow$)), and hence it can be determined by its universal property. So if a category with zero object is complete(like $\mathbf{Grp}$), or at least finitely complete, then all its morphisms have kernels.

**Edit.** The category of groups $\mathbf{Grp}$ is obviously a category with zero object(trivial group), but $\mathbf{Ring}$ is not(see Martin's comment for details).

Comment: The category of rings with unit (which I would denote by $\mathsf{Ring}$) has no zero object, whereas the category of pseudo-rings / non-unital rings has a zero object.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks for correction.

Comment: But you can write A-Modules instead of Rings

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to the notion of [kernel pair](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair). That is, in a category $\mathsf C$, the pullback of a arrow $f \colon A \to B$ along itself : the square
$$ \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\ker f @>>> A \\
@VVV @VVfV \\
A @>>f> B
\end{CD}
$$
is cartesian.

If $\mathsf C$ is the category of sets, then $\ker f = \{ (a,a') \in A \times A : f(a) = f(a') \}$ is an equivalence relation on $A$. Consider then $\mathsf C$ to be $\mathsf{Grp}$, $\mathsf{CRing}$, $R\text{-}\mathsf{Mod}$ etc. : the forgetful functor $U \colon \mathsf C \to \mathsf{Set}$ commutes with (small) limits and so $A \mathop / \ker f$ is the same sets with both definition of $\ker$.

(The "etc." need to be specified, but I'm not qualified enough to do it : don't hesitate to read [this section](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel#other_meanings) of the kernel page on nLab.)

Comment: I know some authors also write about equalisers as the generalisation of a kernel after the analogy of the kernel of a homomorphism $f$ being an equaliser of $f$ and the 0 morphism. Seems like a risky association to promote, but I note it as something someone encountering introductory category theory material might run across.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, I don't understand your comment.  The definition as an equalizer is much more natural than the one in this answer.

Comment: @adeel: I'm mentioning that some introductory category theory books I've read talk about equalisers as "kernels", while there are several other constructions in category theory that bear that name (kernel pairs or kernels in an abelian category). I mention this because the original post is fairly vague, and it's unclear of what kind of generalisation of kernel they might have in mind. I'm trying to point out that some readers may encounter the informal equating of equalisers and "kernels", which is quite different from the above construction and other uses of the term.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, I see.  Usually the term I've seen is "difference kernel" instead of equalizer in older books.